# Replace all characters at once in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I have a mutliple columns with different name format.
For example:

```
df.columns = ['name_column 1 (type1), name-column_2-(type1),...]
```

I need to replace all characters (except underscore) with underscore. But if there is '-(' , I need just one underscore '_', not two for each special character.

Desired output:

```
df.columns = ['name_column_1_type1, name_column_2_type1,...]
```

I have tried with

```
for element in df.columns:
    re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_', element)
    print element
```

But nothing happens, just like in a few other attempts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) + [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_').str.strip('_')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["'name_column 1 (type1)", 'name-column_2-((type1)'])
print (df.columns.tolist())
["'name_column 1 (type1)", 'name-column_2-((type1)']

df.columns =  df.columns.str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_').str.strip('_')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name_column_1_type1, name_column_2_type1]
Index: []

print (df.columns.tolist())
['name_column_1_type1', 'name_column_2_type1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.columns = [re.sub('[^A-z0-9]', '_', i).replace(" ", "_").replace("__", "_") for i in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens because the result of `re.sub` is not assigned to anything and is therefore lost. You could use a list comprehension and assign the result back to `df.columns`:

```
df.columns = [re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_', element) for element in df.columns]
print df.columns
```

Still the regex pattern is wrong, but this should get you started.

Comment: jezrael's answer is better.